# RESTKit: Mapping inconsistency

Tags: core-data, ios7, restkit-0.20

Below is the log of mapping an object with RESTKit.  `startDate` and `modified` both are NSDate in `CoreData`.  The mapping is identical for both.  `startDate` maps fine and the value is shown, but `modified` becomes as `nil`, `0` or `1`.  As you can see in the Log below that the value of `modified` fetched in the `GET` response is not `nil`, `0` or `1`.

Invite.h

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSDate * modified;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSDate * startDate;
```

Log

```
2014-06-22 09:34:15.343 App[86722:3703] T restkit.object_mapping:RKMappingOperation.m:550 Mapping attribute value keyPath 'startDate' to 'startDate'
2014-06-22 09:34:15.344 App[86722:3703] T restkit.object_mapping:RKMappingOperation.m:431 Found transformable value at keyPath 'startDate'. Transforming from type '__NSCFString' to 'NSDate'
2014-06-22 09:34:15.348 App[86722:3703] T restkit.object_mapping:RKMappingOperation.m:572 Mapped attribute value from keyPath 'startDate' to 'startDate'. Value: 2014-06-20 13:30:00 +0000


2014-06-22 09:34:15.350 App[86722:3703] T restkit.object_mapping:RKMappingOperation.m:550 Mapping attribute value keyPath 'comment' to 'comment'
2014-06-22 09:34:15.352 App[86722:3703] T restkit.object_mapping:RKMappingOperation.m:572 Mapped attribute value from keyPath 'comment' to 'comment'. Value: This is a comment

2014-06-22 09:34:15.358 App[86722:3703] T restkit.object_mapping:RKMappingOperation.m:550 Mapping attribute value keyPath 'modified' to 'modified'
2014-06-22 09:34:15.360 App[86722:3703] T restkit.object_mapping:RKMappingOperation.m:431 Found transformable value at keyPath 'modified'. Transforming from type '__NSCFString' to 'NSDate'
2014-06-22 09:34:15.363 App[86722:3703] T restkit.object_mapping:RKMappingOperation.m:572 Mapped attribute value from keyPath 'modified' to 'modified'. Value: 2014-06-19 06:16:55 +0000


2014-06-22 09:34:15.392 App[86722:3703] D restkit.object_mapping:RKMappingOperation.m:1021 Finished mapping operation successfully...
2014-06-22 09:34:15.393 App[86722:3703] D restkit.object_mapping:RKMapperOperation.m:231 Asked to map source object {
    comment = "This is a comment";
    modified = "2014-06-19T07:28:50.000Z";
    startDate = "2014-06-21T07:15:37.000Z";
} with mapping <RKEntityMapping:0xd766f10 objectClass=Invite propertyMappings=(
    "<RKAttributeMapping: 0xd951310 startDate => startDate>",
    "<RKAttributeMapping: 0xd951610 comment => comment>",
    "<RKAttributeMapping: 0xd951620 modified => modified>",
)>


2014-06-22 09:34:16.009 App[86722:3703] D restkit.object_mapping:RKMapperOperation.m:403 Finished performing object mapping. Results: {
    meetings =     (
        "<Invite: 0xdb596a0> (entity: Invite; id: 0xdb34ee0 <x-coredata:///Invite/t8D98B490-5CEC-4EB6-9AD6-533674DA06663> ; data: {\n    comment = \"This is a comment\";\n    modified = 1;\n      startDate = \"2014-06-20 13:30:00 +0000\";\n})",
```

I can't figure out why `startDate` returns the correct value, and `modified` does not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`modified` appears to be a keyword for `RESTKit`.  I changed the `attribute` in `Core Data` to `modifiedDate` and it seems to work fine.